# PHP - how to get nth(first, second, etc) key and value for array?

Tags: php, laravel

I have array :

```
$test = ['10' => 'a', '20' => 'b'];
```

I want get key and value for first and second element, e.g. something like

```
echo 'first array key is ' . array_key($test, 0);//10
echo 'second array key is ' . array_key($test, 1);//a
echo 'first array value is ' . array_value($test, 0);//20
echo 'second array value is ' . array_value($test, 1);//b
```

any ideas ?

PS. I don't want solution with

```
foreach ($test as $key => $value ){...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can store all the keys and values in variables using [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) and [array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) i.e.,

```
$keys = array_keys($test);
$values = array_values($test);
```

And then, use them as follows:

```
echo 'first array key is ' . $keys[0]
echo 'first array value is ' . $values[0]
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use this for get first:

```
$element = array_chunk($test, 1, 1);
var_dump( $element[0]);
```

or something like this for easy get all sub arrays:

```
list($first, $second) = $test;
print_r($first);
print_r($second);
```